# Glue Spark: Some task has 0 records for shuffle but some task has disk spill

Tags: apache-spark, aws-glue, amazon-emr

I have a spark job where some task has zero records output and shuffle read size where some task have memory and disk spill. Can some one help me what can I do to optimize the execution.
Execution Info: repartition_cnt=3500   [ datasets is in S3 and execution is through Glue G2X with 298 DPUs)

Code:

```scala
fct_ate_df.repartition(expr(s"pmod(hash(mae_id, rowsin, dep), $repartition_cnt)"))
       .write
       .mode("overwrite")
       .format("parquet")
       .bucketBy(repartition_cnt, "rowsin", "rowsin","dep")
       .sortBy("rowsin","dep")
       .option("path", s"s3://b222-id/data22te=$dat22et_date")
       .saveAsTable(s"btemp.intte_${table_name}_${regd}")
```

Summary Metrics
[image]

No record output/shuffle
[image]

Spill record

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using reparition by expression and i think that this the reason why you see those empty partitions. In this case internally spark is going to use HashPartitioner and this partinioner does not guarantee that partitions are going to be equal.

Due to Hash algorithm you are sure that records with the same expression value are going to be in the same partition but you may end up with empty partitions or with partitions which has for example 5 keys inside.

In this case numPartitions is not changing anything, in case of many keys in one bucket (so later partition) which at the end are generating less partitions than numPartition Spark is going to generate empty partitions as you can see in your example

I think that if you want to have equal partitions you may remove this expression in which you are calculating hash and leave only $repartition_cnt

Thanks to that Spark will use RoundRobinPartitioner instead and this one will generate equals partitions

If you want to dig dipper you may take a look at source code, i think that here are nice starting points

Here you can find logic connected to repartition without expression: [Spark source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ee1c624fa03d15e6b71b0ecef044ee3c9167a812/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/logical/basicLogicalOperators.scala#L1676)

Here you can find logic which is used for partitioning by expression: [Spark source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ee1c624fa03d15e6b71b0ecef044ee3c9167a812/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/logical/basicLogicalOperators.scala#L1691)

Regards!